# 未然形＋んが grammar?

Tags: grammar

> などと、目をキラッキラと輝かせながら、皆を**呑み込まんが**如く両手を大きく広げる。

I know the general meaning of the sentence but what is the grammar phenomenon of 未然形＋んが? Is it a fixed structure?

Answer (score 3):

This can be remembered as a literary set phrase, but it's technically a [remnant of the grammar of classical Japanese (文語)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42724/5010). In modern Japanese, it's 皆を呑み込もうとするかのように両手を大きく広げる.

- **呑み込ま**: the 未然形 of 呑み込む
- **ん**: the 連体形 of the classical volitional/conjecturing auxiliary [む](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009010.htm). The 連体形 worked as a nominalizer in classic Japanese. よう(とすること) in modern Japanese.
- **が**: the archaic possessive particle. の in modern Japanese.
- **如く**: the 連用形 of the classical adjective-like auxiliary [如し](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009030.htm). ように in modern Japanese.

Related:

- [Auxiliary verb ん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23924/5010)
- [Is there a difference between んがため and ために?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5396/5010)
- [Verb ending in -ん with positive meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72064/5010)
- [meaning of ~に於るが如く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83026/5010)
- [Why is there a が in 深淵に臨むが如し?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70684/5010)

Comment: Is かの required in するかのように? Is it possible just to say するように?