# Grammar of -がために

Tags: grammar, particles

I've seen a few sentences with this, "(~る)がために" construction, however whenever I look it up I just get grammar points about "(ないーform)んがために". Is "(~る)がために" just a more emphasized version of regular ために?

The sentences (they are unrelated to each other)

1. 惰性に身を任せてい**るがために**今のような現在があるんですね。
2. おまえさんとこのジョーは自分の身を守**るがために**わしらの子どもまでまきぞえにしとるんやで。
3. しかもそれらは一般に常用され**るがために**日々増えている。
4. あなたが公園ででくわすほとんど全てのいやな出来事は、妖精たちがあなたに悪意をもって**るがために**起きることです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, 任せているために is the modern plain version, whereas 任せているがために is its literary (and perhaps emphatic) equivalent. This が is an archaic possessive/noun-linking particle that is still in use in a few fixed constructions including this one. ～んがために is a literary version that also has an archaic volitional auxiliary む/ん.

Modern ために means both "because" and "in order to", but I think `plain-form + がために` tends to mean the former because it lacks む/ん. For example, 車を買いたいがために貯金する sounds fine, but 車を買うがために貯金する and your second example sound a little unnatural to me, if not wrong. 車を買わんがために貯金する and 身を守らんがために sound much more natural (although stilted).

|  | ために | がために | む + がために |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Godan | 買うために <sub>in order to buy because someone buys</sub> | 買うがために <sub>(usu.) because someone buys</sub> | 買わんがために <sub>in order to buy</sub> |
| Ichidan | 見るために | 見るがために | 見んがために |
| Suru | するために | するがために | せんがために |
| Past | したために | したがために | N/A |
| Na-adj | 有名であるために 有名なために | 有名であるがために 有名がために <sub>(rare)</sub> | N/A |
| I-adj | 美しいために | 美しいがために | N/A |

For details, please see the following questions:

- [「が」vs「の」 with possessives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39264/5010)
- [Is there a difference between んがため and ために?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5396/5010)
- [Why is there a が in 深淵に臨むが如し?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70684/5010)
- [未然形＋んが grammar?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88664/5010)

Comment: Wouldn't it better to describe this use of が as appositive (㋓同格。…という。) or content-indicating (② 下の形式名詞（「から、ごと、むた、まにま、ため」等）の実質、内容を示す。), or, more broadly, attributive, rather than possessive? (The glosses in parentheses are taken from here: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8C-456340)

Comment: @goldbrick 古語のガの同格用法は「我らが二人」とか「明日が日」のような例があるようですが、稀のようですし意味的にも違う気がします。「見る、即ち、タメ」ということではないので。広く attributive とか noun-linking と言っておく分には間違いないと思うのですが、まあノ/ガの代表的用法が possessive であり content-indicating というのもその派生だということで…

Comment: 同格関係を「即ち」で表す場合は、「が」「という」で表す場合の前項と後項が逆転すべきではないでしょうか。「我ら(が/という)二人」「明日(が/という)日」「見る(が/という)為(=理由)」⇔「二人、即ち、我ら」「日、即ち、明日」「為(=理由)、即ち、見る(こと)」　Anyway, as always it's gracious and conscientious of you to respond to and try to accommodate other people's inputs as mush as you see fit. Thanks!