# Meaning of せん in そのすべてに感謝せん

Tags: word-usage

> 大地の精霊よ
> イシの村にもたらす恵み
> そのすべてに感謝せん

I am wondering if this is perhaps a shortened version of an expression like 感謝の言葉もありません or something like that?

I've tried looking in jisho for せん but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: Disregard that, this is a different せん that comes from せむ (old equivalent of しよう). I had a bit of a brainfart, sorry.

Comment: Here, I'm not sure if either of these are duplicates, but they're definitely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/is-there-a-difference-between-%e3%82%93%e3%81%8c%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81-and-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ab?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33867/what-is-the-verb-ending-of-%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%82%93-mean. Also - this is from Dragon Quest XI, right?

Comment: Yes, from Dragon Quest XI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This せん is not a negation. そのすべてに感謝せん here means "Let us thank all of them". It's そのすべてに感謝しよう in modern Japanese.

せ is the 未然 (irrealis) form of す ("to do") in classical Japanese, just as し is the 未然 (irrealis, pre-nai) form of する in modern Japanese. ん is a shortening of む, which is a volitional auxiliary in classical Japanese.

- [Auxiliary verb ん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23924/5010)
- [Verb ending in -ん with positive meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72064/5010)
- [Is there a difference between んがため and ために?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5396/5010)